# How to store data in a variable which itself is in the list of varibales?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here is the code:

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame()
df6 = pd.DataFrame()
df7 = pd.DataFrame()
df8 = pd.DataFrame()
df9 = pd.DataFrame()
chunk_size = 4
dfList = [df5, df6, df7, df8]
for i in range(4):
    dfList[i] = pd.DataFrame(np.array_split(dframe,chunk_size)[i])
```

Now, I want to access the data stored in dfList[0] df5, but when printing df5, I get an empty dataframe. When I print dfList[0] it gives the correct output. Why is it so and can I get the output directly by printing df5?

Comment: What you try to achieve mean that you create a list dList with the references of previous variables. But this is not possible in python, because python don't support pointers this way. What happens when you create your list dList is that variables are copied in the new list dList you create and you cannot modified that variable by modifying in the list because they are not sharing anymore the same reference (or pointer if you are familiar with C)

Comment: With that in mind, you can mutate dfList[i] instead of assigning to it: `dfList[i].insert(0, 0, pd.DataFrame(np.array_split(dframe,chunk_size)[i]))`